# Xcode problem with date class

Tags: c++, xcode, class

I keep getting the same error in a program that is supposed to just be a simple date class.
These are warnings

```
start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

This is the code.

```
// Lab 2: Date.cpp
// Member-function definitions for class Date.
#include <iostream> 
using std::cout; 

#include "Date.h" // include definition of class Date


Date::Date( int m, int d, int y ) 
{
    setDate( m, d, y ); // sets date 
} // end Date constructor

void Date::setDate( int mo, int dy, int yr )
{
    setMonth( mo ); // invokes function setMonth 
    setDay( dy ); // invokes function setDay
    setYear( yr ); // invokes function setYear
} // end function setDate

void Date::setDay( int d )
{
    if ( month == 2 && leapYear() )  
        day = ( d <= 29 && d >= 1 ) ? d : 1; 
    else
        day = ( d <= monthDays() && d >= 1 ) ? d : 1;
} // end function setDay

void Date::setMonth( int m ) 
{ 
    month = m <= 12 && m >= 1 ? m : 1; // sets month  
} // end function setMonth

void Date::setYear( int y ) 
{
    year = y >= 1900 ? y : 1900; // sets year
} // end function setYear

int Date::getDay() 
{
    return day;
} // end function getDay

int Date::getMonth() 
{ 
    return month; 
} // end function getMonth

int Date::getYear() 
{ 
    return year; 
} // end function getYear

void Date::print()
{
    cout << month << '-' << day << '-' << year << '\n'; // outputs date
} // end function print

void Date::nextDay(int d)
{
    d=d+1;
}
bool Date::leapYear()
{
    if ( getYear() % 400 == 0 || ( getYear() % 4 == 0 && getYear() % 100 != 0 ) )
        return true; // is a leap year
    else
        return false; // is not a leap year
} // end function leapYear

int Date::monthDays()
{
    const int days[ 12 ] =  
    { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

   return getMonth() == 2 && leapYear() ? 29 : days[ getMonth() - 1 ];
} // end function monthDays
```

and here is the .h file

```
// Lab 2: Date.h
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

class Date 
{
public:
   Date( int = 1, int = 1, int = 2000 ); // default constructor
   void print(); // print function
   void setDate( int, int, int ); // set month, day, year
   void setMonth( int ); // set month
   void setDay( int ); // set day
   void setYear( int ); // set year
   int getMonth(); // get month
   int getDay(); // get day
   int getYear(); // get year 
    void nextDay(int);
private:
   int month; // 1-12
   int day; // 1-31 (except February(leap year), April, June, Sept, Nov)
   int year; // 1900+
   bool leapYear(); // leap year
   int monthDays(); // days in month 
}; // end class Date

#endif
```

Comment: Try to make a minimal example that reproduces your error. Chances are, that during the construction of such minimal example you'll find the error yourself

Comment: Indeed. Can you compile a simple hello world?

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, you're not trying to compile a *program* without a `main` function, are you? If so, you're going to get a compilation error.

As an aside, you should be aware that your `nextDay` function probably doesn't do what you think it does.

```
void Date::nextDay(int d)
{
    d=d+1;
}
```

Since you're passing `d` in by value, this simply increments a *copy* of `d` and then exits. If you intended to modify the original value, you should change the function signature to `void Date::nextDay(int& d)`.

Comment: where would I insert the int main() and the return?

Comment: @MrWolvz I would probably put it in `main.cpp`.

Comment: @MrWolvz Did you figure this out?

Comment: I did not. The name of the file is main.cpp but what within the first code would the int main() encompass? Does it go before the constructor or after or what?

Comment: can you still help me with this? Sorry, didn't realize the @ person command.

Comment: Every program needs to have a `main` function (e.g. `int main() { // your code }`). Make sure that yours does.

Comment: I know it need it, I just don't know what is enclosed by the main function. Does it come before or after the constructor and is there one needed in the .h file?